# Fox Moons - Enigmatic Puzzle

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, geography

[image: Fox Moons]

Clues:

9JPJ+RM9 Bath
CRMX+V4 Mexico City
HX8H+M7 Seoul
JMC2+67 Seattle
G2R6+FX7 Salida
P4VX+RP Queens
JMC2+67 Seattle
V75V+8VG Paris
V75V+8VG Paris
V7FV+CWP Paris
CRMX+V4 Mexico City
9GQJ+VQC Qatar
4R96+2P Las Vegas
QH48+Q7 Bangkok
RHG9+49 Bangkok
V7FV+CWP Paris
G2R6+FX7 Salida

[2 33 1 40] x 
[1 
22 
200 
18.175]

(contextual images)

Instructions:
Name That Celestial Body

---

Hint:

> Try using the satellite view. 
>  [image: S Mountain Salida]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given the coordinates, we can find the following places.

9JPJ+RM9 Bath

> Royal Victoria Park in UK
>  [image: Royal Victoria Park-UK]

CRMX+V4 Mexico City

> A building near Monumento A La Revolućion
>  [image: A building near Monumento A La Revolućion]

HX8H+M7 Seoul

> Seoul City Hall
>  [image: Seoul City Hall]

JMC2+67 Seattle

> Space Needle
>  [image: Space Needle]

G2R6+FX7 Salida

> Greens Creek Hiking Trail
>  [image: Greens Creek Hiking Trail]

P4VX+RP Queens

> Terrace on the Park in Queens
>  [image: Terrace on the Park in Queens]

V75V+8VG Paris

> Eiffel Tower
>  [image: Eiffel Tower]

V7FV+CWP Paris

> Arc de Triomphe
>  [image: Arc de Triomphe]

9GQJ+VQC Qatar

> Katara Towers in Doha
>  [image: Katara Towers in Doha]

4R96+2P Las Vegas

> Westgate Las Vegas
>  [image: A building in Las Vegas]

QH48+Q7 Bangkok

> G Tower
>  [image: G tower-Bangkok]

RHG9+49 Bangkok

> Elephant tower
>  [image: Elephant Tower-Bangkok]

The notable fact about these places is that each building/place resembles a letter in Engilsh alphabet. Together they spell (according to the given order):

> [**Christiaan Huygens**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christiaan_Huygens), the person who discovered the largest moon of Saturn, [**Titan**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_(moon)).

And the product of matrices equals to

> **1655**, the year in which Titan was discovered.

Therefore the final answer is

> **TITAN**.

OP Edit:

> Additionally, the profile shown is Matt Damon from the Team America movie. Matt Damon played Cale in the film Titan AE, by Fox Animation.

Answer (score 4):

So here is a partial answer.

The matrix given in the picture equals to

> 1655.

which corresponds to

> the discovery year of Titan, which is probably the answer.

Regarding the clues

9JPJ+RM9 Bath corresponds to

> Royal Victoria Park.

CRMX+V4 Mexico City corresponds to

> Monumento A La Revolućion. </!>

HX8H+M7 Seoul corresponds to

> Cheonggyecheon.

JMC2+67 Seattle corresponds to

> Space Needle.

GR26+FX7 Salida corresponds to

> Greens Creek Hiding Trail.

P4VX+RP Queens corresponds to

> New York Hall of Science.

V75V+8VG Paris corresponds to

> Tour Eiffel.

V7FV+CWP Paris corresponds to

> Arc de Triomphe.

9GQJ+VQC Qatar corresponds to

> Actually the result obtained was for 9GQJ+QVC which was Lasail Murina Promenade.

49RG+2P Las Vegas corresponds to

> A point in the ocean.

QH48+Q7 Bangkok corresponds to

> Victorv Monument.

RHG9+49 Bangkok corresponds to

> Major Cineplex Rachavothin.

I do not have an explanation for clues and title.